# React JS - element focus on input not working

Tags: reactjs, focus, onkeydown

I'm having trouble with focusing element programmatically.
I have a ul which looks like this :

```
      <ul className="text-left">
        {Object.keys(props.characters).map((char, i) => {
          return (
            <li key={props.characters[char].key}>
              <button type="button" className={"btn align-middle bg_" + props.characters[char].character}>
                <div className={"label text-left float-left " + getFontColorFromCharacter(props.characters[char].character)}>
                  <img alt="" className="char-img" src={"/images/characters/" + props.characters[char].character + "_xs.png"}/>
                  <input className="align-middle d-none" id={props.characters[char].key + "_input"} type="text" placeholder="Nom joueur" value={props.characters[char].player_name} onChange={e => props.changePlayerNameHandler(props.characters[char],e)} onBlur={e => toggleDNone(props.characters[char].key)} onKeyDown={e => tabToNext(e)}/>
                  <span className="align-middle" id={props.characters[char].key + "_span"} onClick={e => toggleDNone(props.characters[char].key)} > {props.characters[char].player_name}</span>
                </div>
                <div className={"actions " + getFontColorFromCharacter(props.characters[char].character)}>
                  <span className="action">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="times-circle" title="Supprimer" onClick={() => props.removeCharacterHandler(props.characters[char].key)}/>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
```

Javascript :

```
//Toggle d-none class on input & span for player name edition
function toggleDNone(key) {
    document.getElementById(key + "_input").classList.toggle("d-none");
    document.getElementById(key + "_span").classList.toggle("d-none");

    if (!document.getElementById(key + "_input").classList.contains("d-none")) {
        document.getElementById(key + "_input").focus();
    }
}

//When the user hit tab key, navigate to next input
function tabToNext(event){
    if(event.key === "Tab")
    {
        var allInput = document.querySelectorAll("[id$='_input']");

        var indexOfCurrent = Array.from(allInput).indexOf(event.target);
        var id;
        if (indexOfCurrent + 1 === Array.from(allInput).length)
        {
            id = allInput[0].id;
        }
        else
        {
            id = allInput[indexOfCurrent + 1].id;
        }

        toggleDNone(allInput[indexOfCurrent].id.replace("_input", ""));
        toggleDNone(id.replace("_input",""));
    }
}
```

When the users click on the span, the input is displayed and the focus is working. When the users hit the tab key to get to the next input, the input is displayed but the focus is not working.

I tried setting the tabIndex to -1 as I saw on a post but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us your full React component ?

Comment: I edited the question ;) The full component is way to big to put here.

Comment: Why don't you use onFocus handler?

Comment: I don't want to do something when the element is focus, i just want to set the focus on the element.

Comment: Can you explain why do you have for starters span/input  combination? This could be surely achieved in more simple manner.

Comment: It's just aesthetic, I didn't want the input to be displayed all the time.

Comment: Don't do that, increasing DOM tree and doing HTML antipatterns... Just style input to your likings depending on focus state... You can disable default appearance with css appearance property...

Comment: Thx Mario, I will optimize that when I finished all the basic features ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution.
The issue was that the second toggleDNone call started before the first one finished.

I just added a setTimeOut of 100ms on the second call and it worked.

Thanks all